# Problem accessing wiki page with MediaWiki 1.32, PHP is out of date

Tags: php, mediawiki, wiki

I'm currently running a wiki website that's supported by MediaWiki. The site was made a while ago and I've never used the MediaWiki software to manage it before. The new update to MediaWiki 1.32 apparently causes an internal error on my wiki site apparently and returns the following when I try accessing it:

> MediaWiki 1.32 internal error
>
> MediaWiki 1.32 requires at least PHP version 7.0.13 or HHVM version 3.18.5, you are using PHP 5.6.39.
>   Supported PHP versions
>
> Please consider upgrading your copy of PHP. PHP versions less than 5.6.0 are no longer supported by the PHP Group and will not receive security or bugfix updates.
>
> If for some reason you are unable to upgrade your PHP version, you will need to download an older version of MediaWiki from our website. See our compatibility page for details of which versions are compatible with prior versions of PHP.

Is there a way to update PHP for my website without needing to use the MediaWiki software? If not, is there a way to retrieve the information on the website?

Thanks

Comment: Do you manage the server or is it managed by your host?

Comment: Its managed by the host

Answer (score 0):

You have to install PHP 7.0.13 or an higher version.

[Here](https://windows.php.net/download/) you can find the latest version of php and upgrade it manually

[Here](https://help.one.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005585569-How-do-I-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-PHP-) you can find a step by step guide to do that